# How to detect changes in the list of objects where there are new properties?

Tags: angular, angular8

I have a component . Inside it I show a list of objects by ngFor.

The object is changing in the template, but I can’t get the changes in the controller(pages.component.ts)

This is a new angular 8. [my code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xjxkw7)

Comment: please elaborate your question, it's really hard to understand what do you want to achieve. provide as much details as possible, go through this link to understand how to ask - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NgOnChanges` is called only if you change the old object on new object. Modifing some fields of existing object isn't calling `ngOnChanges`.

If you need invoke `NgOnChanges`, you must replace input object on new, for example

```
this.pages[1] = Object.assign({}, this.pages[1], {modifiedField: 'new value'});
```

I just clone the existing object in new object and append fields that I need modify